# How do i redirect to a page from button click in react from a component?

Tags: reactjs

this is my app.js

```
<div
  className="flex-one main-content-box"
  style={{ height: "calc(100% - 55px)" }}
>
  <div className="arrow-navigation" style={{ top: topPosition }}></div>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/" exact render={() => <DashBoard store={main} />} />
    <Route path="/newprocess" render={() => <div>DEFG</div>} />
    <Route path="/release" render={() => <div>ABCD</div>} />
  </Switch>
</div>
```

this is my process.jsx

```
<div className="saveblue mg-r-10" onClick={this.handleNewProcess} style={{cursor: "default"}}><i className="fas fa-plus pd-r-5" />New Process</div>
```

this the function

```
 handleNewProcess = () => {
        //HOW DO I REDIRECT THE CLICK FROM HERE TO "/newprocess" page 
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [programmatically-navigate-using-react-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `useNavigate()`.

```
    import { useNavigate} from "react-router-dom";

    const MyCompo= () => {
    
      let navigate = useNavigate();
      handleNewProcess = () => {
         navigate(`/newprocess/`);
        //HOW DO I REDIRECT THE CLICK FROM HERE TO "/newprocess" page 
    }
```

And as nos nart mentioned, this solution is fit only from react-router v6.

Comment: See the render props on Route comp. OP use react-router-dom v5 not v6

Comment: Hi @nosnart, can you please explain what do you mean? you mean useNavigation is working only on version 5?

Comment: v5 doesn't have `useNavigate` hooks

Comment: i have used useHistory but its not working do i have to render anything ?

Comment: UseHistory is deprecated see the link https://github.com/frontarm/navi/issues/137

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve this issue using useHistory hook

```
    import { useHistory} from "react-router-dom";

    const MyCompo= () => {
    
      let history = useHistory();
      handleNewProcess = () => {
         history.push('/newprocess/');
        //HOW DO I REDIRECT THE CLICK FROM HERE TO "/newprocess" page 
    }
```

checkout this page ,  it has mentioned all the methods of redirection in react:
[Link](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks)